# After removed lubuntu-desktop, still got lubuntu lockscreen

Tags: 13.04

I installed lubuntu-desktop, removed it, and now I still got the lubuntu lockscreen.

Since yesterday it is even worse, now when I unlock my session I have the unlock screen from lubuntu, then the one of ubuntu !

(I installed lubuntu-desktop)

Answer (score 1):

In fact `sudo apt-get remove lubuntu-desktop` doesn't remove all the lubuntu stuff.

I had to list all the packages containing lubuntu : `dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall`

And remove them.